# How to get the correct order of copying files in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, tree

I'm using python to copy some files. But I can't get the correct copying order.

Assume I have a class:

```py
class Info:
    def __init__(self, source: str, destination: str):
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination
```

And I have a list of `Info`.

The rule of copy order is:

**If A.destination contains B.source, put B behind A.**

e.g.
Here we have three `Info`

```
 Id        source         destination
Info1      Root/A    ->    Root/B/A
Info2      Root/B    ->    Root/D/B
Info3      Root/C    ->    Root/A/C
```

Info1.destination contains Info2.source, so put Info2 behind Info1,

Info3.destination contains Info1.source, so put Info1 behind Info3.

The final order is `[Info3, Info1, Info2]`

I think the biggest difficulty is some `Info` can't be compared.

Is there some efficient algorithm to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by `topological sort`, I find a version in [here](https://gist.github.com/kachayev/5910538):

```
from collections import deque
from collections import defaultdict

GRAY, BLACK = 0, 1

def topological(graph):
    order, enter, state = deque(), set(graph), {}

    def dfs(node):
        state[node] = GRAY
        for k in graph.get(node, ()):
            sk = state.get(k, None)
            if sk == GRAY: raise ValueError("cycle")
            if sk == BLACK: continue
            enter.discard(k)
            dfs(k)
        order.appendleft(node)
        state[node] = BLACK

    while enter: dfs(enter.pop())
    return order
```

test code:

```
graph = defaultdict(list)
graph['A'].append('B')
graph['B'].append('D')
graph['C'].append('A')

src_info = {'A': 'Info1', 'B': 'Info2', 'C': 'Info3'}
res = [src_info[c] for c in topological(graph) if c in src_info]

print(res)
```

output:

```
['Info3', 'Info1', 'Info2']
```

Comment: Thanks tell me about `topological sort`, I use package `networkx` to solve this problem. Thanks a lot!